# Dead lock in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am using WPF and SQLite. I have a SQLite file in Network, when two user try to save  Data at same time the SQLite throw Dead lock Exception. How can I solve this problem? Here is this error

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.CommitFailedException: An error was reported while committing a database transaction but it could not be determined whether the transaction succeeded or failed on the database server. See the inner exception and http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=313468 for more information. ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: database is locked
database is locked
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteTr`enter code here`ansaction.Commit()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually say "Dead lock Exception," it says database lock exception.  In a deadlock, no one gets the resource.  In your case, it appears that one user has the lock, and the other user is being starved out.

Comment: You also need to give us more context for the conditions under which this exception is happening.

Comment: If database is lock i wait for to release the database lock and then goes another user request. is it possible.